# Failure Scenarios in IP networks

Tags: ip

I am searching for a list of faults that may occur in a traditional IP network.

To give you a better understanding of what I am looking for:

- For an MPLS-IP network the set of faults may be something as given in this [cisco](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/net_mgmt/ip_solution_center/6.0/mpls_failure_scenarios/user/guide/mde_fail.html) site.

I want pointers to such kind of faults for a traditional IP network.

Individual suggestions from you are welcome, but in doing so, please also provide a link to
the official site from which you came with those failure scenarios.

Comment: Experiance tells me you cannot prodict every thing. You will allways miss something. and there has to be a cost/Risk ratio.

Comment: nobody is going to do your homework for you, fault list can go on and on, there is not a single answer to this.

Comment: I am just asking for a list of standard probable causes. I am sure that there must be a standard specification somewhere, as this is essential for Root Cause Analysis. I am not asking anyone to do my homework for me. I am just saying, such a list is already available, and if someone knows where to find it, please let me know.

Comment: maybe something link this? - https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-4227

Comment: Why has this question been voted down? Atleast give your reason for voting it down.

Comment: @ColdT : Thanks for the pointer. But, unfortunately that was not what I was looking for. I, myself have given the link for MPLS in my question. What I am looking for is a similar document, but for traditional IP-Ethernet networks.

Comment: This isn't a very good serverfault question. It's way too broad and it's asking for lists. Also note the text when you hover the mouse over the downcheck- SF isn't your personal research assistant.

Answer (score 1):

backhone attenuation is a common problem affecting all types of data networks. this includes IP networks. as requested link to credible source: http://etherealmind.com/networking-term-backhone-attenuation/